# How did they consider \$I_{3_{min}}\$ and \$I_{3_{max}}\$ in 4-20 mA current transmitter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb-design

Define the minimum and maximum currents through R<sub>3</sub>. See Design Note #5 before defining these currents.

For this design, \$I_{3_{min}}\$ = 20 μA, \$I_{3_{max}}\$ = 100 μA are chosen.

[This link](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoaa73/snoaa73.pdf) has the document with the design steps.

How did they consider \$I_{3_{min}}\$ and \$I_{3_{max}}\$ current values while calculating R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub>, which again depend on R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub>, without initially finding R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub>?

Comment: Perhaps the OP could edit to make the question stand alone??

Comment: Without clicking through, we can't even tell what device you're asking about.

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking.  The 4-20mA numbers come from standard industrial communication protocols.

Answer (score 2):

You pick (say) the minimum current i3_min. **You** are picking this number, and there is a range of values that would be acceptable (it’s effectively a degree of freedom). Too much current and it might draw too much current for the input or even to cause problems with Iq of the transmitter. Too low and the op-amp input bias current may cause too much error. They chose 20uA for i3_min, probably 10uA or 40uA would also be fine.

That determines i3_max = (i3_min)*(20mA/4mA) and you can calculate R1 and R2 to achieve those numbers.